# What should be the alternate of Hover on Mobile Devices?

Tags: mobile, hover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad/iPhone alternative for hover states](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8918/ipad-iphone-alternative-for-hover-states)
>   [Re-thinking “hover” functionality with touchscreens in mind](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/re-thinking-hover-functionality-with-touchscreens-in-mind)

We have our intranet application using the Megflyouts in the Menu. So when we hover over a menu item it displays the Megaflyout with number of Navigation and information options. Also on click on the Menu Item we go to that page. In a mobile device where Hover and click are basically one thing. How do you think we can re-design the same stuff to let two functionalities work independently and still look intutive.

Comment: I'd argue a mega-menu likely doesn't make much sense on a small hand-held to begin with.

Comment: Well i was talking abt ipad in particular.

Answer (score 4):

On a desktop hovering opens, and clicking activates; on a touch device change it to tapping opens, and tapping again activates. You can indicate the fact that the item is clickable on the second tap by using standard link text decoration (underlined) when the megaflyout appears, as shown below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foIVAJ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>