# Mouse over gesture in touch interface

Tags: hover, mouse, dashboard, tablet, gestures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some alternatives to “hover” on touch-based devices?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-are-some-alternatives-to-hover-on-touch-based-devices)

I'm looking for a touch gesture/ other solution  that would replace a mouse over indication ( like we see on a desktop application or a website) for a tablet app.
The screen I'm working on is a dashboard app much like Google analytics.

Comment: Here is a similar question [What are some alternatives to “hover” on touch-based devices?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-are-some-alternatives-to-hover-on-touch-based-devices)

Comment: And a few others ([1](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/re-thinking-hover-functionality-with-touchscreens-in-mind), [2](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/970/what-are-some-alternatives-to-hover-on-touch-based-devices), [3](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21845/what-should-be-the-alternate-of-hover-on-mobile-devices)).